# Convert SQL default instance to named instance

Tags: sql-server

My server is already in production with SQL Server default instance. Can I now move or convert or migrate this same default instance to a named instance?

I need to do this on the same host or server. Please guide how to perform this?

Regards,

Comment: Install a named instance on the same host and follow the same steps as you would to migrate to a new server (copy logins, jobs, etc, and restore databases).

Comment: You cannot "convert" or "rename" an existing instance to something else. The name of the instance can **only** be set at the time of installation. If you want a second, named instance - just install SQL Server again, with that desired instance name

Comment: Alternatively you can create an alias: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120306/create-an-alias-for-a-sql-server-named-instance-pointing-to-sql-default-instance

Comment: Should I install named instance, restore DB from default instance to named instance and later stop default instance? Is it possible to stop default instance alone without interfering named instance?